# count no of instance of tuple with same value in some attribute

Tags: mysql, database, count, group-by, rdbms

i have following database

```
=================================
**id(PK)    orderid      email_content**
----------------------------------------------
1           6544        complain regarding service   
2           6544        request for replacement
3           6544        complain for late delievery
4           9822        thanking note
5           5762        faulty product
6           5762        complain for
```

what i need is no of time interaaction per order
that is for each orderid , how many time email is present
for example for 6544 order4 id we have 3 emails..and like wise

```
orderid      no_of_iteraction
-------------------------------
6544         3
9822         1
5762         2
```

please suggest appropriate mysql query

Comment: this is table not database. and what is the name of your table

Comment: slip of tongue rahil..apologies..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT orderid, COUNT(orderid) no_of_iteraction
FROM tblTemp 
GROUP BY orderid
```

**OR**

As per your request using **SUM** function

```
SELECT orderid, SUM(1) no_of_iteraction
FROM tblTemp 
GROUP BY orderid
```

**OR**

```
SELECT orderid, SUM(cnt)
FROM (SELECT orderid, 1 cnt FROM tblTemp ORDER BY orderid) AS A 
GROUP BY orderid
```

Comment: is there any way we can do this by SUM ?

Comment: Why you want to do this using sum

Comment: just to know if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(id) as no_of_iterations, orderid from mytable group by orderid
```

Comment: is there any way we can perform same via SUM function ??

Comment: no using sum will result something different. i means it will show sum as 6 against 6544. adding 1 , 2 and 3